# What is a native build environment?

Tags: cmake

I am simply reading information off the interwebs, currently the [cmake about page](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/project/about.html), and I need the information to fill in the gaps, it helps to see the big picture.

Surely the answer is straightforward, I hope. What is a native build environment?

Context: I need to know **how** to build software on my machine (CodeBlocks, etc), why I need to do this, the advantages of doing this, etc. But first, I need to know every piece of jargon I come across, and I could not find any explanations about exactly what a "Native build environment" is, although I can speculate to some degree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

["Native"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_%28computing%29) as in "runs directly in the host operating system" and not "runs in a virtual machine or emulator."

The particular point that CMake's about page is trying to convey is the manner in which CMake achieves cross-platform functionality: specifically *not* by virtualizing, but by cooperating/collaborating directly with the host system, and the "normal" ways the host system is used to doing things.

> Is the build environment then just the directory holding all the garbage needed for a compiler to build the software then?

That's an oversimplification – there's nothing to say that it's a single directory – but more or less, yes. The term is not jargon, it literally means "the state of the world" (aka, environment) needed for the build.

> What would you call the other thing then, Non-native?

Sure, or virtualized, or emulated, or whatever other intermediate layer has been added.

> Why do we need the distinction as well?

Why not? It's useful to have a concise, clear, simple term so we can communicate precisely and with minimal confusion and ambiguity.

Comment: Okay, that helps. Is the build environment then just the directory holding all the garbage needed for a compiler to build the software then? It seems obvious enough to make that assumption at this point. What would you call the other thing then, Non-native? Why do we need the distinction as well?

Answer (score 1):

Why 'non-native'? If you haven't already figured this out - there is something called cross-compilation.

Simply put, if I don't have access to target hardware (or an equivalent virtual machine) on which the software needs to run, how do I develop this software on my host and package it to run on that target?

Cross-compilation addresses this by providing necessary tools that perform a translation (or other important low-level stuff) to give you the final software. Such an environment to develop software is called non-native.

Well, I believe we need the term to state the technique.